# Looping function over range which changes each year

Tags: r, loops

**PROJECT** - collecting topic information from Australian High Court decisions published online to analyse trends over time.

**CURRENT PROBLEM** - trying to iterate 'case_importer' function (which returns relevant character strings from decisions) over each year a number of times equal to the number of cases decided in that year.

I can achieve this manually by using a for loop which iterates as many times as there were cases each year - using 2020 (which has had 14 cases so far) for example:

```
for (i in 14) {
  hc_cases_2020_list[[i]] <- case_importer(2020, i)
}
```

However, I would rather not have to rewrite the number of iterations for each year manually.

I have stored the number of cases per year in an excel sheet called 'hc_cases_per_year' which has two columns, 'year' and 'num_cases', and created a function which gives the 'num_cases' value with a year input.

Any advice in solving the specific problem or taking a better approach would be beyond appreciated.

My code so far is below - thanks for taking the time to read!

````
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

# Function to import html data and turn it into text

html_to_text <- function(url) {
  url %>%
    read_html %>%
    html_nodes("li , p , blockquote , b , h2") %>%
    html_text
}

# Function to extract topic paragraphs using grep

grep_topics <- function(text) {
  grep("^\\n?(:?\\w+\\s)+\\(?C?t?h?\\)?\\s?–.*", text, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)
}

# Function to wrap the above funtions into a single function that takes year and case number

case_importer <- function(year, case_num) {
  url <- url_maker(year, case_num)
  text <- html_to_text(url)
  grep_topics(text)
}```

# Function + command to create empty list for each year

list_namer <- function(year) {
  assign(paste0("hc_cases_", year, "_list", sep = ""), list(), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

for (i in 1948:2020) {
  list_namer(i)
}

# Function to change list to dataframe 

list_to_df <- function(list) {
  num_obs <- sapply(list, length)
  seq_max <- seq_len(max(num_obs))
  t(sapply(list, "[", i = seq_max))
}

# Function to return number of cases in given year

cases_in_year <- function(year) {
  hc_cases_per_year$num_cases[year - 1947]
}

# Function to create a URL for any given year and case number

url_maker <- function(year, case_num) {
  paste("http://classic.austlii.edu.au/au/cases/cth/HCA/", year, "/", case_num, ".html", sep = "")
}

# Importing hc_cases_per_year

hc_cases_per_year <- read_excel("PATH/hc_cases_per_year.xlsx")
````

Comment: Can you post `dput(head(hc_cases_per_year))` to share first few rows of `hc_cases_per_year` ? And what is the expected output you are looking for?

Comment: > dput(head(hc_cases_per_year))
structure(list(year = c(1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953), 
    num_cases = c(48, 69, 58, 77, 74, 97)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

I'm trying to output a different list for each year, but also allow the function to iterate over those lists a number of times equal to the cases in each year. 

e.g. for the 1950 list, I would like my code which extracts the data to run 58 times - first on 1950 case 1, then 1950 case 2, and so on - putting each of them into the appropriate list.